# MixPre D (USB Audio Class compliant device) - Windows XP only shows outputs - no inputs!

Tags: usb, windows

Hello! I'm having issues with a mixpre d - tried it on 2 different computers, both running windows xp - and it only shows up any volume controls for playback in the windows volume control thingy.. it DOES have a recording section (you can click the little circle to the left of "recording") - but this section is entirely empty..

anyone know how to fix this, or the same thing with any other class compliant device? (how does windows decide what to show here?? i have a really cheap usb sound card that shows up as having inputs on here even though it actually doesn't have any!!)

thanks if you can help!! :)

Comment: Maybe check XP version: is it SP3 ? (Service Pack 3)

Answer (score -1):

Well, if anyone's interested, i got a signal through anyway.. guess there's no point allowing attenuation in windows just to confuse things, when it's at unity gain anyway..

i did have to alter the session to 16 bits before it would work though.. guess there must be a bit depth setting on the unit somewhere..

Answer (score -2):

Digital recording volume controls don't generally make a lot of sense in high-end recording interfaces as you'd have to place them into the analog circuitry to make even remote sense, and then they would cause noise of their own above the quantization noise of high-end converters.

Some recording interfaces have an internal mixer (digital or analog) in order to deliver a minimal-delay monitoring signal: for that purpose controls may exist, but they don't affect the recorded signals.